# Preventing wrong density plots when coloring histograms according to groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

based on some dummy data I created a histogram with desity plot

```
set.seed(1234)
wdata = data.frame(
  sex = factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
  weight = c(rnorm(200, 55), rnorm(200, 58))
)
a <- ggplot(wdata, aes(x = weight))

a + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..,
                       # color = sex
                       ), 
                   colour="black",
                   fill="white",
                   position = "identity") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2,
               # aes(color = sex)
               ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF"))
```

[image: Basic Result]

The histogram of  `weight` shall be colored corresponding to `sex`, so I use `aes(y = ..density.., color = sex)` for `geom_histogram()`:

```
a + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..,
                       color = sex
                       ), 
                   colour="black",
                   fill="white",
                   position = "identity") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2,
               # aes(color = sex)
               ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF"))
```

[image: Scaled individual histograms (not desired)]

As I want it to, the density plot stays the same (overall for both groups), but the histograms jump scale up (and seem to be treated individually now):

How do I prevent this from happening? I need individually colored histogram bars but a joint density plot for all coloring groups.

P.S.
Using `aes(color = sex)` for `geom_density()` gets everything back to original scales - but I don't want individual density plots (like below):

```
a + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..,
                       color = sex
                       ), 
                   colour="black",
                   fill="white",
                   position = "identity") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2,
               aes(color = sex)
               ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF"))
```

[image: Individual densities (not desired)]

**EDIT:**

As it has been suggested, dividing by the number of groups in `geom_histogram()`'s aesthetics with `y = ..density../2` may approximate the solution. Nevertheless, this only works with symmetric distributions like in the first output below:

```
a + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density../2,
                       color = sex
                       ), 
                   colour="black",
                   fill="white",
                   position = "identity") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2,
               ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF"))
```

which yields

[image: Solution]

Less symmetric distributions, however, may cause trouble using this approach. See those below, where for 5 groups, `y = ..density../5` was used. First original, then manipulation (with `position = "stack"`):
[image: Original]

[image: Divided by 5]

Since the distribution is heavy on the left, dividing by 5 underestimates on the left and overestimates on the right.

**EDIT 2: SOLUTION**

As suggested by Andrew, the below (complete) code solves the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
wdata = data.frame(
  sex = factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each = 200)),
  weight = c(rnorm(200, 55), rnorm(200, 58))
)

binwidth <- 0.25
a <- ggplot(wdata,
            aes(x = weight,
                # Pass binwidth to aes() so it will be found in
                # geom_histogram()'s aes() later
                binwidth = binwidth))

# Basic plot w/o colouring according to 'sex'
a + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),
                   binwidth = binwidth,
                   colour = "black",
                   fill = "white",
                   position = "stack") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF")) +
  # Use fixed scale for sake of comparability
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(52, 61)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.25))


# Plot w/ colouring according to 'sex'
a + geom_histogram(aes(x = weight,
                       # binwidth will only be found if passed to
                       # ggplot()'s aes() (as above)
                       y = ..count.. / (sum(..count..) * binwidth),
                       color = sex),
                   binwidth = binwidth,
                   fill="white",
                   position = "stack") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF")) +
  # Use fixed scale for sake of comparability
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(52, 61)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.25)) +
  guides(color = FALSE)
```

**Note:**
`binwidth = binwidth` needed to be passed to `ggplot()`'s `aes()`, otherwise the pre-specified `binwidth` would not be found by `geom_histogram()`'s `aes()`. Further, `position = "stack"` is specified, so that both versions of the histogram are comparable. Plots for dummy data and the more complex distribution below:

[image: Correct, ungrouped, simple data]

[image: Correct, grouped, simple data]

[image: Correct, ungrouped, more complex distribution]

[image: Correct, grouped, more complex distribution]

Solved - Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just use `y = ..density../2` in your second version.

Comment: Original question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it using `y=..density..`, but you can recreate the same thing like this...

```
binwidth <- 0.25 #easiest to set this manually so that you know what it is

a + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count.. / (sum(..count..) * binwidth),
                       color = sex), 
                   binwidth = binwidth,
                   fill="white",
                   position = "identity") +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF"))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'binwidth' not found`. How did you avoid this?

Comment: Are you sure you've set `binwidth <- 0.25` (or whatever value you want) - the message suggests it has not been defined before you draw the chart?

Comment: Thanks again! `binwidth = binwidth` had to be passed to the `aes()` of `ggplot()`. Great! Complete code in edit above ...